# parse JSON with gson and GsonBuilder()

Tags: json, gson

```
String jsons = "{'appname':'application', 'Version':'0.1.0', 'UUID':'300V', 'WWXY':'310W', 'ABCD':'270B', 'YUDE':'280T'}";
```

This is my json string. How can i parse it to GsonBuilder() that i will get object back? I try few thinks but none works.

I also read https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
public class YourObject {
   private String appname;
   private String Version;
   private String UUID;
   private String WWXY;
   private String ABCD;
   private String YUDE;
   //getters/setters

}
```

parse to Object

```
YourObject parsed = new Gson().fromJson(jsons, YourObject.class);
```

or

```
YourObject parsed = new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(jsons, YourObject.class);
```

minor test

```
String jsons = "{'appname':'application', 'Version':'0.1.0', 'UUID':'300V', 'WWXY':'310W', 'ABCD':'270B', 'YUDE':'280T'}";
YourObject parsed = new Gson().fromJson(jsons, YourObject.class);
```

works well

**EDIT**
in this case use `JsonParser`

```
JsonObject object = new JsonParser().parse(jsons).getAsJsonObject();
object.get("appname"); // application 
object.get("Version"); // 0.1.0
```

Comment: what about without new class? I don't need new class

Comment: @Ilya Is it possible to get the output as ArrayList rather than YourObject..

Please look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30163699/google-map-direction-api-using-retrofit .... I need ArrayList<LatLng> as output of the retrofit..

Comment: Saved me days of re-coding

Answer (score 3):

JSON uses double quotes (`"`), not single ones, for strings so the JSON you have there is invalid. That's likely the cause of any issues you're having converting it to an object.

Comment: so i need to check json string if is valid. Is try catch enought?

Comment: @senzacionale That depends on whether or not it throws an exception if you pass it invalid JSON; I assume that it would, so using a try-catch block should be sufficient.